# how to use the “required” attribute in Yii booster radioButtonListRow

Tags: html, yii, radio-button, yii-booster

Does Anyone know how to use the "required" attribute in Yii booster radioButtonListRow for client side validation only?

```
echo $form->radioButtonListRow($model, 'radioButtons', array(
        'Option one',
        'Option two',
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with yiibooster. Yii deals with it. In your model you can mention rules like which attribute is required

```
array('your attribute', 'required'),
```

and you can use this as

```
echo $form->radioButtonListRow($model, 'your attribute', array(
       '0'=> 'Option one',
        '1'=>'Option two',
    ));
```

Yii will automatically validate the attribute you have mentioned